# What are the necessary phenomenons/effects needed to create laser destructive enough to burn steel (103mm thickness) in its path with a single sweep

Tags: science-based, technology

What kind of phenomenon do we need to achieve that kind of destructibility.

If possible not a chemical based lasers but i'll welcome all of the answers

Comment: A *very slow* sweep would work right now....

Comment: You are basically referring to a laser CNC machine.  They exist.

Answer (score 8):

### Need more information

The information you've provided is insufficient to provide a quantitative answer (laser aperture size, laser frequency, quality of the atmosphere, sweep speed, distance, beam shape, etc. all go into the calculations).

### Rough estimate

However, you will need something in the multi-megaWatt or larger size range (larger than the largest currently existing on Earth).  In principal, there is nothing to prevent our current era (CE) technologies from building one of these now.

### Candidate laser

The largest chemical laser I know of is the Deuterium Flouride ($D_2 + F_2 \rightarrow 2\cdot DF$) [Mid-infrared Advanced Chemical Laser (aka MIRACL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIRACL) found at White Sands New Mexico.

This (very large and immobile) *One MegaWatt Class* chemical laser does **not** have enough power to do what you want.

### More detailed estimate

#### Assume:

1. Density of steel $\rightarrow 8.05 \frac{g}{cm^3}$
2. One dimensional analysis
3. Specific heat of solid ($c_{solid}$) $\rightarrow 0.5 \frac{J}{g \cdot °C}^a$
4. Specific heat of liquid iron ($c_{liquid}$) $\rightarrow 0.82 \frac{J}{g \cdot °C}^a$.
5. Heat of vaporization ($\Delta H_{vap}$) $\rightarrow 267 \frac{J}{g}$
6. Heat of fusion ($\Delta H_{fus}$) $\rightarrow 277 \frac{J}{g}$
7. Melting point of iron ($1410 °C$)
8. Boiling point of iron ($2861 °C$)
9. The required energy to penetrate equals the energy required to
   vaporize the material in front of the $\text{beam}^{\text{b,c}}$
10. Thickness of steel is 10.3 cm
11. Dimensionless mass is $10.3 cm \times 8.05 \frac{g}{cm} = 83 g$

#### The numbers

The equations to calculate this value are:

1. Fluence $^d$ to heat steel to melting point
   temperature $$\rightarrow F_{\text{heat sol}} = m \cdot c_{sp} \cdot \Delta
       T = 83 \cdot 0.5 \frac{J}{g \cdot °C} \cdot 1390 °C = 57,626 J$$
2. Fluence to melt steel $$ \rightarrow F_{melt} = m \cdot \Delta
       H_{fus} = 83 g \cdot 277 \frac{J}{g} = 22,967 J$$
3. Fluence to heat steel to vaporization temperature $$\rightarrow
       F_{\text{heat liq}} = m \cdot c_{sp} \cdot \Delta
       T = 83 g \cdot 0.82 \frac{J}{g \cdot °C} \cdot 1451 °C = 98,654 J$$
4. Fluence to vaporize steel $$ \rightarrow F_{vap} = m \cdot \Delta
       H_{vap} = 83 g \cdot 277 \frac{J}{g} = 22,138 J$$
5. **Total Fluence** to vaporize $$\rightarrow F_{Tot} = 57,626 J + 22,967
       J + 98,654 J + 22,138 J = 201,386 J$$

### Discussion

To give you an idea of what this Fluence really means, consider that the *aperture power* of the Navy's shipboard prototype laser is ~30 kW - meaning if you put your steel plate *at the aperture* of the laser (so that you get no beam losses) and focused it down to a $1 cm^2$ spot, it'll take that laser ~7 seconds to burn through a 103 mm steel plate.

#### Time

The total above Fluence ($201,386 J$) represents the total energy that must be deposited onto the unit area of the target.  Longer dwell times allow more time for conduction, convection, beam dispersal by aerosols, etc. to reduce the efficiency of the beam and remove the destructive energy of the beam from the damage site.

In order to account for this, longer dwell times should adopt some sort of fudge factor, probably scaling asymptotically towards some minimum *on-target* beam power.  If the *on-target* beam power falls below this value, it will never penetrate.

#### Space

Also this dimensionless number is representative of a 1 cm spot on the target.  At any reasonable engagement range, your beam will diverge to a region much larger than this.

To account for beam spreading use the [equations from Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunconvent.php#id--Laser_Cannon--Equations) to calculate your likely beam size at a given range using a specific laser frequency.

*Integrate* the on-target beam power distribution over area and dwell time to get the required *on-target* energy.  Conversely to get beam power, divide fluence required (the *minimum* is given above) by time and multiply by size to get the required *on-target* beam power.

### Notes

a. I use iron's values for these numbers because it's difficult to find all of them for many steels.  Expect the numbers for steel designed for use as armor to be somewhat higher than these.
b. A beam laser which requires long dwell times, will increase the amount of energy required to penetrate due to a variety of factors.
c. A pulse laser with properly tuned pulses can penetrate materials using a mechanism called [Impulsive Shock](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunconvent.php#id--Nukes_In_Space--Impulsive_Shock) with less energy than that required to vaporize the whole thickness of metal.
d. Fluence is a measure of Energy divided by area (aka it is the area dimensionless Energy).

(Really these are integrations but I'm giving you the following equations to explain the difference between the beams energy, power, fluency, & intensity)

Beam energy (in $J$):
$$E_{beam} = I_{beam} \times A_{beam} \times T_{\text{dwell time}} = P_{beam} \times T_{\text{dwell time}} = F_{beam} \times A_{beam}$$

Beam fluence (in $\frac{J}{cm^2}$):
$$F_{beam} = \frac{E_{beam}}{A_{beam}} = I_{beam} \times T_{\text{dwell time}}$$

Beam power (in $W = \frac{J}{sec}$):
$$P_{beam} = \frac{E_{beam}}{T_{\text{dwell time}}} = I_{beam} \times A_{beam}$$

Beam intensity (in $\frac{W}{cm^2} = \frac{J}{cm^2 \cdot sec}$):
$$I_{beam} = \frac{E_{beam}}{A_{beam} \cdot T_{\text{dwell time}}} = \frac{P_{beam}}{A_{beam}} $$

Comment: I plan to elaborate in more detail later.  However, we could calculate the required on target energy.  Figuring out the at aperture energy from that wouldn't be possible without the other information.

Comment: My quoted number of 24,000 J (per gram) seems low.  I noticed I forgot to convert volume to mass so that's a factor of 10 too low just from that.  I'll check the rest of my math later.

Comment: [XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/13/) comes to mind here.

Comment: There was a [500 TW laser shot from a few years ago](http://phys.org/news/2012-07-nif-history-terawatt-laser-shot.html). It was for a very short time of course, but did deliver 1.85 MJ to the target. It seems relevant. Thanks for doing the math +1

Comment: @Samuel, the difference is between power and energy.  The 500 TW shot was instantaneous power.  The shots are such short duration (e.g. picoseconds), that they don't really have much energy in them.  Although both parameters are important (higher power is generally preferred to lower power), energy is the number you should use for a first order analysis.

Comment: @Jim2B I'm well aware of the difference, which is why I provided the energy delivered. The example I gave, 500 TW delivering 1.85 MJ, was for 3.9 nanoseconds. Or 3,900 picoseconds if you want to use that unit.

Comment: @Samuel, I apologize.  I didn't read your comment carefully enough.

Comment: This also neglects weapons effects, which came as an unpleasant surprise to early laser enthusiasts.  Once the outer layers of a target have been vaporized, they do not magically disappear. For deep cuts it takes significant time and energy to clear the vapor away so the laser can cut deeper. While it remains in the beam it will continue to absorb energy, and may even reflect it. For a deep hole this is a real problem.

Comment: That's why I assume *first order analysis*!  Unless the target is moving, you get aerosolized target blocking your shot.  Some metals (e.g. Aluminum) get super shiny and reflect the beam better.  Some composites (graphite-epoxy) out-gas, become carbon-carbon, and get very difficult to damage.  Which exact mechanism is important in each engagement depends upon the engagement's specifics.  I don't care to mess with those!

Comment: Your answer suggests no, but then you cite an existing laser and suggest that this laser could do it in 7 seconds. That sounds contradictory. Is this given an assumption that that laser could not be sustained for 7 seconds, or is there some other reason to reject it?

Answer (score 2):

The ever popular "Atomic Rockets" site has most of the equations you need to determine the sort of laser weapon energy, cooling system and power input you need for virtually any situation:

http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunconvent.php

For the sort of device you are thinking of, here is the verbal description of the Ravening Beam of Death (RBoD), a massively powerful Xaser weapon, which is effective out to one light second, and can cause significant damage one *light minute* away (the Earth's Moon is just slightly outside the RBoD's ideal engagement range, and any target on the Lunar surface could easily be burned by the RBoD in Earth orbit.)

> Laser guru Luke Campbell thinks it not impossible to make an x-ray laser which does NOT require a nuclear device to pump it. In theory a Free Electron laser can produce any wavelength. It is possible approximate an x-ray lens by having the rays make glancing blows off dense materials.
>
> Bottom line is an x-ray laser is technologically very challenging, but if you manage to make one you have an Unstoppable Death Ray of Stupendous Range.
>
> Let's take a 10 MW ERC pumped FEL at just above the lead K-edge. This particular wavelength is used because lead is pretty much the heaviest non-radioactive element you can get, and at just above the highest core level absorption for a material you can get total external reflection at grazing angles - so no absorption or heating of a lead grazing incidence mirror. We will use a 1 meter diameter mirror. The Pb K-edge x-ray transition radiates at 1.4E-11 m. This gives us a divergence angle of 1.4E-11 radians. At 1 light second, we get a spot size of 5 mm, and an intensity of 5E11 W/m2.
>
> Looking at the NIST table of x-ray attenuation coefficients, and noting that 1.4E-11 m is a 88 keV photon, we find an attenuation coefficient of about 0.5 cm2/g for iron (we'll use this for steel), 0.15 cm2/g for graphite (we'll use this for high tech carbon materials) and 0.18 cm2/g for borosilicate glass (a very rough approximation for ceramics). Since graphite has a density of 1.7 g/cm3, we get a 1/e falloff distance (attenuation length) of 4 cm. Iron, with a density of 7.9 g/cm3, has an attenuation length of 0.25 cm. Glass, density 2.2 g/cm3, has an attenuation length of 2.5 cm.
>
> At 1 light second, therefore, the beam is depositing 2E12 W/cm3 in iron at the surface and 7E11 W/cm3 at 0.25 cm depth; 1.2E11 W/cm3 in graphite at the surface and 5E10 W/cm3 at 4 cm depth; and 2E11 W/cm3 in glass at the surface and 7E10 W/cm3 at 2.5 cm depth. Using 6E4 J/cm3 to vaporize iron initially at 300 K, we find that iron flashes to vapor within a microsecond to a depth of 0.9 cm. The glass, assumed to take 4.5E4 J/cm3 to vaporize (roughly appropriate for quartz) will flash to vapor within a microsecond to a depth of 4 cm within a microsecond. Graphite, at 1E5 J/cm3 for vaporization, will flash to vapor to a depth of 0.7 cm within a microsecond (the laser performs better if we let it dwell on graphite for a bit longer, we get a vaporization depth of 10 cm after ten microseconds).
>
> Net conclusion - ravening death beam at one light second.
>
> Now lets look at one light minute. The beam is now 30 cm across. This is much deeper than the attenuation length in all cases, so we will just find the radiant intensity and the equilibrium black body temperature of that intensity. We have an area of 7E-2 m2, and an intensity of 1.4E8 W/m2. You need to reach 7000 K before the irradiated surface is radiating as much energy away as heat as it is receiving as coherent x-rays. The boiling point of iron is 3023 K, the boiling point of quartz is 2503 K, and the sublimation temperature of graphite is 3640 K. All of these will be vaporized long before they stop gaining heat. At this range, the iron is subject to 5.6E8 W/cm3 at the surface, the graphite to 3.3E7 W/cm3 at the surface, and the glass to 5.6E7 W/cm3 at the surface. Using the above values for energy of vaporization, we get about 0.1 milliseconds before the iron starts to vaporize, 0.8 milliseconds before the glass starts to vaporize, and 3 milliseconds before the graphite begins to vaporize (because of its long attenuation length, once it begins to sublimate, graphite sublimates rapidly to a deep depth, while you essentially have to remove the iron layer by layer).
>
> Net conclusion - still a ravening death beam at one light minute.
>
> What about at one light hour? The beam is 18 meters across. The equilibrium black body temperature is 900 K. This is well below the melting point of most structural materials. Ten megawatts, however, is a lot of ionizing radiation. Any unhardened vehicle will be radiation killed at these ranges.
>
> Luke Campbell
>
> However, he goes on to note that in order to boost electrons to the velocities required for an X-ray free electron laser, you will need an acceleration ring approximately one freaking kilometer in diameter. So this X-ray laser would only be suitable for exceedingly huge warships, orbital fortresses, and Death Stars.
>
> Since the time he wrote the above, Luke Campbell has reconsidered the use of lead grazing incidence mirror. Now he favors using diffraction.
>
> I have since come to realize that at x-ray energies this high, matter cannot act as a mirror even at grazing angles (the x-rays have such a short wavelength that they interact with the atoms individually, rather than seeing them as a flat sheet - and you can't really get grazing incidence off of an individual atom). This is why I now prefer diffraction for focusing.

Remember, don't try this at home....